# BSModelservice callback function returning error. I am using angular 6 and ngx-bootstrap/modal

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components, ngx-bootstrap

I am getting below exception.

> ERROR TypeError: this.callBackOnSave.emit is not a function

Child Component

```
@Input() showDeleteBtn: boolean = true;
@Input() showGrid: boolean = true;
@Output() callBackOnSave: EventEmitter<null> = new EventEmitter();

this.callBackOnSave.emit();
```

Parent component

```
callBackOnSave(){
  console.log("got it***");
}

const initialState = {
  showDeleteBtn: false,
  showGrid: false,
  callBackOnSave: 'callBackOnSave()'
};

this.modalService.show(ScheduleComponent, {class: 'modal-md',  initialState});
```

Can anyone faced this issue. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are keeping this statement `this.callBackOnSave.emit();` outside of function. I don't think you will be doing this blunder but wondering by looking at your question. If yes then move inside the method if not then share the more code.

Comment: Child component:                                                                                            save() {
    this.buttonsComponent.save();
    if(!this.showGrid){
      this.callBackOnSave.emit();
    }
  }

Comment: Issue is somewhere else. Could you share the entire code for child component ?

Answer (score 0):

How does your Parent component's template look? it should have something like

```
<app-child-component (callBackOnSave)="callBackOnSave($event)">...</app-child-componen>
```